# Defining a function to express one element of a pair

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to formulate a complex system and I'm just not sure about how to define a function to get an element of a pair, which is also an element of a set of pairs.

I won't get into details of the system as it is irrelevant but basically I can say that in the system, there are agents $A_n$ and each has a set of $B_n$ which consists of pairs $<A_i, T_j>$. $B_n$ set is used to keep a $T_j$ value for other agents ($A_i$).

Now, I would like to get the value of $T_j$ that the agent $A_n$ holds for the agent $A_i$ (in short, the $T_j$ part of the $<A_i, T_j>$ pair).

So basically I want a function like $f_a(A_n,A_i)$ that could give me the value of $T_j$ that is a part of the $<A_i, T_j>$ pair, which is an element of the set $B_n$. In order to do that, I defined a function using the arrow notation:

$$f_a: A_n,A_i \mapsto T_j \in <A_i, T_j> \in B_n$$

But this just doesn't feel right and I'm not even sure if this notation is mathematically correct. I feel like there should be a better way to do it.

If anyone can help me with this, I would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: such a function is called a *projection*.

Let's be a bit more precise. A function always needs a domain (where it takes its input from) and a codomain (the possible outputs). In your case, the input of your function is going to come from the set $B_n$. The output will be a value $T_j$. You did not specify in your post what kind of value that is, but let us say all the possible values $T_j$ are collected in $P_T$ (as you mentioned in the comments below). So we will end up getting a function $f_n: B_n \to \mathcal{T}$, specified by $\langle A_i, T_j \rangle \mapsto T_j$. We call this *projection on the second coordinate*.

Now, you really want a function that takes two agents $A_n$ and $A_i$ as input. That function should then look in $B_n$ at the entry $\langle A_i, T_j \rangle$ and output $T_j$. This in itself is already a precise description of a function, but if you wish to use a bit more notation then that is possible. For the definition to be well-defined, you need that for every $B_n$ and for every agent $A_i$ there is precisely one entry $\langle A_i, T_j \rangle$ in $B_n$ (If there are none, what would be our output? If there is more than one, which would we choose?). Denoting the collection of all agents as $P_A$ we then get a function $f: P_A \times P_A \to P_T$ defined by $\langle A_n, A_i \rangle \mapsto T_j$ such that $\langle A_i, T_j \rangle \in B_n$. For this last sentence there is no (standard) shorter notation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yeah, I forgot to mention that all the agents come from a set called $P_A$ and I also defined a set called $P_T$ for all the $T_j$ values used within the set $B_n$. So in that case, I can define the domain and codomain like $f_n : B_n \to P_T$, and specify it like $f : <A_i,T_j> \mapsto T_j$ as you specified, and then define the function $f$ like $f : P_A \to P_T$ by saying $A_n,A_i \mapsto f_n(<A_i,T_j>) such that <A_i,T_j> \in B_n$, is that correct? Because I need to use 2 inputs $A_n$ and $A_i$.

Comment: @Repercussion Ah, so you want it to be some sort of function that looks up the value $T_j$ corresponding to $A_i$? That wasn't clear to me. If by definition there is precisely one $A_i$ such that $\langle A_i, T_j \rangle \in B_n$ then this is correct. Although your input is now a pair $\langle A_n, A_i \rangle$ (you take two inputs), so $f$ goes from $P_A \times P_A$ to $P_T$ and you should write "$\langle A_n, A_i \rangle \mapsto f_n(\langle A_i, T_j \rangle)$ such that $\langle A_i, T_j \rangle \in B_n$".

Comment: That last bit can even be simplified to "$\langle A_n, A_i \rangle \mapsto T_j$ such that $\langle A_i, T_j \rangle \in B_n$".

Comment: @Repercussion I have edited my answer to reflect these comments.

Comment: thank you very much, I've been struggling with it for days :)